# Convenient access to members of raw pointers?

Tags: rust

The notation for accessing nested members of raw pointers for instances we know don't need to be checked against NULL can be rather awkward:

```
struct MyLink {
    link: *mut MyLink,
}
```

```
let var = *(*(*(*root).link).link).link;
```

Can raw pointer's struct members be accessed without having to explicitly de-reference each time? Maybe by using methods like `root.link().link().link()` or by wrapping the type?

While idiomatic Rust avoids this, there are exceptional cases where it isn't so easy to avoid. `Rc` has memory overhead, borrow checker causes problems for inter-linking members, C-API may require pointers... etc.

Comment: Have you tried the wrapper method approach? I'm also very curious about that edge case.

Comment: @E_net4, I didn't try it yet (not sure how it would be written), but seems like the most promising solution.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that "[pointers in Rust] don't need to be checked against NULL".  References have that property (can't be null), which is why the borrow checker is applied to them (to prevent dangling references).  Pointers, on the other hand can be null, but the safety check for them is that they cannot be dereferenced outside of an `unsafe` block.

Comment: @ampron Very true. However, I believe the question is to be interpreted as "they don't have to be checked in my use case".

Comment: @E_net4 I agree

Comment: Updated question to avoid confusion, I meant in this particular case. (maybe delete last 3 comments to avoid noise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a recurring situation in your code, I'd just create a generic wrapper.

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Hash)]
struct Ptr<T> {
    ptr: *mut T
}

impl<T> Ptr<T> {
    pub unsafe fn new(ptr: *mut T) -> Ptr<T> {
        debug_assert!(!ptr.is_null());
        Ptr { ptr: ptr }
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn as_pointer(&self) -> *mut T {
        self.ptr
    }
}

impl<T> Deref for Ptr<T> {
    type Target = T;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &*self.ptr }
    }
}

impl<T> DerefMut for Ptr<T> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        unsafe { &mut *self.ptr }
    }
}

impl<T> Copy for Ptr<T> { }
impl<T> Clone for Ptr<T> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn clone(&self) -> Ptr<T> { *self }
}

impl<T> PartialEq for Ptr<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Ptr<T>) -> bool {
        self.ptr == other.ptr
    }
}
```

We assert upon construction that the `ptr` is effectively not null, so we do not have to check again when dereferencing.

Then we let the language check for `Deref`/`DerefMut` when calling a method or accessing an attribute:

```
struct MyLink {
    link: Ptr<MyLink>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut link = MyLink { link: unsafe { Ptr::new(1 as *mut _) } };
    let next = MyLink { link: unsafe { Ptr::new(&mut link as *mut _) } };
    let _ = next.link;
}
```

Comment: does this add any overhead to release builds, compared with using a raw pointer?

Comment: @ideasman42: it should not, after optimizations. The methods are trivial enough to be inlined. If this worries you, you can slap `#[inline(always)]` on top of `deref` and `deref_mut`.

Comment: Great, this is what I'd assume, also interested to know how `MyLink { link: Ptr::new(1 as *mut _) };` could be written a little more compact, I guess macros could work as a last resort.

Comment: @ideasman42: with a constructor function accepting `*mut MyLink` :)

Comment: The non-null assertion does not seem to have any utility; the property is not used anywhere, and there are other ways than null for a pointer to be wild and wrong.

Comment: @bluss: While I agree there are other ways for a pointer to be invalid than being null, null is certainly the easiest to catch, so I see no harm in catching at least *some* issues. As for not being used anywhere, isn't forming a reference from a null or dangling pointer incorrect? I have the feeling I should mark `Ptr::new` as `unsafe`.

Comment: Sure, of course that's incorrect and there's no assertion that can make it safe. I feel it should be a debug assertion if it's not used to ensure an invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper methods can indeed improve readability of that code. Just by following [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/raw-pointers.html#references-and-raw-pointers):

```
struct MyLink {
    link: *mut MyLink,
    pub n: i32,
}

impl MyLink {
    pub unsafe fn link(&self) -> &MyLink {
        &*self.link
    }

    pub unsafe fn mut_link(&mut self) -> &mut MyLink {
        &mut *self.link
    }
}
```

Whether to mark the method prototype as `unsafe` or not is up to your particular case, but the implementation must be in an unsafe block: fetching a reference from a pointer, even without dereferencing, is not safe.

Using it:

```
unsafe {
    let mut l1 = MyLink {
        link: 0 as *mut MyLink,
        n: 4,
    };

    let mut l2 = MyLink {
        link: &mut l1 as *mut MyLink,
        n: 3,
    };
    let n1 = l2.n;
    let n2 = l2.link().n;
    println!("{} -> {}", n1, n2);
}
```

[Gist](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c6cf42d5f5c6a3a6c82b1d45acc3add7&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom method for raw pointers in exactly the same way as for any other Rust type:

```
trait WickedRef<T>{
    unsafe fn wicked_ref<'x>(self) -> &'x T;
}

impl<T> WickedRef<T> for *mut T{
    unsafe fn wicked_ref<'x>(self) -> &'x T{
        &*self
    }    
}

root.link.wicked_ref().link.wicked_ref()
```